# How to open an android app using a deeplink that contains a token?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, deep-linking, ionic-native

I'm generation an android application from an ionic application , and i want to open it when i click on a registration link that contains a token ( http://localhost:8100/signup/token) using deeplinks. How can i do that and how to pass the token parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want this plugin: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks

It's all explained in the Github page, but let's see:

1 - Install the plugin:

```
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks
--variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com
--variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/
```

With the DEEPLINK_SCHEME + URL_SCHEME parameters you set the domain that detects links and takes the user to your app. In the example above:

https://myapp

But this is a native functionality that you can only test on a device, not with ionic serve.

2 - Then in your app.component.ts:

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.deeplinks.route({
        '/about-us': HomePage,
        '/products/:productId': HelpPage
      }).subscribe(match => {
        // match.$route - the route we matched, which is the matched entry from the arguments to route()
        // match.$args - the args passed in the link
        // match.$link - the full link data
        console.log('Successfully matched route', match);
      },
      nomatch => {
        // nomatch.$link - the full link data
        console.error('Got a deeplink that didn\'t match', nomatch);
      });
});
```

To get your parameter, use a route like 'signup/:token', and you can get that parameter ('argument') in match.$args, as you can see above.

Comment: The problem is that when i write http or or https as a url_scheme it doesn't work

Comment: also when i write localhost:8100 as a host it doesn't work too (http://localhost:8100)

Comment: First, http or https is not the url_scheme, that's the deeplink_scheme: DEEPLINK_SCHEME://URL_SCHEME. So localhost would be the url_scheme, and https the deeplink scheme.

Comment: Second, obviously it won't work with localhost. What I've suggested you is a native plugin, you need to test it in your device using a scheme like: https://  myapp